# Why didn't they check the Cylon ship that crashed into the Galactica?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

Battlestar: Galactica - Season 2 Episode 1 and 2

A Cylon ship crashes into the Galactica at the end of Season 2, episode 1 but no one bothers to investigate the crashed ship,even after they jumped away to safety (which incidentally carried multiple Cylons inside it). Why is this? Seems like a glaring oversight on the part of the crew.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Galactica was massively undercrewed for battle operations (it was a museum ship), and there was almost no elapsed time within the show between the end of the first episode and the start of the next one, so no-one investigates because there hasn't been enough time for someone to investigate.

The cylons are quickly discovered by the pilots who've just landed, and the command crew are alerted to the boarders soon after, by which time the crew have more urgent problems.